# assistance with mongodb setup on windows server

Tags: mongodb

I am currently setting up Mongo DB on a dedicated web server. I am not experienced with Mongo so I have some questions around its setup. I have done research in to Mongo etc but would like some assistance/direction on the following:

- on the windows server this will be running on I will have an anti virus running on the server. Are there any files on mongo that I should avoid scanning?
- in the area of clustering, what is the default/recommended setup for this? In what manner should it be setup in an enviornment it is storing data for a front wcf application.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't scan the folder in which mongodb stores it's data files, as this will degrade performance. The location is set by using the `--dbpath C:\Where\You\Want\The\Files` flag at runtime.

With regards to best practices for clustering, I'd recommend taking a look at the [Infrastructure Requirements for a Sharded Cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-clusters/#infrastructure-requirements-for-sharded-clusters) page.

At a minimum, you will need **three config servers, two or more shards and one or more MongoSes**